# Python : Finding the longest pair strings in a dictionary ( values)?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dict

```
{'longbutnotlongestpair1':['longbutnotlongestpair2' ,'longbutnotlongestpair3'], 'thisisshort1': ['thisisshort2'] , 'thisisthelongeststring1' : ['thisisthelongeststring2','thisisthelongeststring3'], 'thisisthelongeststring4' : ['thisisthelongeststring5','thisisthelongeststring6']}
```

And I want to find the longest pair of strings.

output (that I want):

```
['thisisthelongeststring2','thisisthelongeststring3']
['thisisthelongeststring5','thisisthelongeststring6']
```

this is what I have so far

```
for i in D.keys():
    if max(D.keys(), key=len):
        print(D[i])
```

obviously there is an error,
also `max()` is not going to work, since it will only return one thing, and I might have two or more max to return.

Any ideas how to achieve my desired output?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by longest pair of strings. Did you mean the total length of the two strings in a pair?

Comment: assume that all pairs have the same length already, I want to find the longest string that has a pair

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to adjust your `max` `key` function to fit your criteria better:

```
maximum_key = max(D, key=lambda k: sum(len(v) for v in D[k]))
print(D[maximum_key])
```

Here the key takes the sum of all lengths in `D[k]`. If you wanted to find the one value with the longest *single* string, use:

```
maximum_key = max(D, key=lambda k: max(len(v) for v in D[k]))
```

to use the maximum single-string length of each value to find the maximum key.

If, however, you must list *all* longest pairs, you could  sort your keys instead, then pick those with the same length of string values. Using `groupby` will help pick out just the longest keys:

```
from itertools import groupby

key = lambda k: sum(len(v) for v in D[k])
maximum_keys = next(groupby(sorted(D, key=key, reverse=True), key=key))[1]
for max_key in maximum_keys:
    print(D[max_key])
```

This picks the *first* group of the keys, sorted in reverse by string lengths, and gives you *just* those keys that all have the same length. This is the maximum key group, which we then print.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> D = {'longbutnotlongestpair1': ['longbutnotlongestpair2', 'longbutnotlongestpair3'], 'thisisshort1': ['thisisshort2'], 'thisisthelongeststring1': ['thisisthelongeststring2', 'thisisthelongeststring3'], 'thisisthelongeststring4': ['thisisthelongeststring5', 'thisisthelongeststring6']}
>>> key = lambda k: sum(len(v) for v in D[k])
>>> maximum_keys = next(groupby(sorted(D, key=key, reverse=True), key=key))[1]
>>> for max_key in maximum_keys:
...     print(D[max_key])
... 
['thisisthelongeststring2', 'thisisthelongeststring3']
['thisisthelongeststring5', 'thisisthelongeststring6']
```

This is reasonably performant, but if you have a very large dictionary and / or large values, you want to sorting (O(NlogN) cost), or looping twice (once to get the maximum, once to print the values).

You can do this all with just *one* loop to determine the maximum values:

```
max_values = []
max_length = 0
for value in D.values():
    res = sum(len(s) for s in value)
    if res > max_length:
        max_length = res
        max_values = [value]
    elif res == max_length:
        max_values.append(value)

for value in max_values:
    print(value)
```

Comment: According to the question, all the longest pairs should be listed if there are not only one.

Comment: @Skyler: ugh, need more caffeine this morning. Now it actually works too.

Comment: Cool. Please help review my answer if you like:)

Answer (score 0):

```
sumlen = lambda x:sum([len(i) for i in x])
maximum = max([sumlen(i) for i in D.values()])
for i in D.values():
    if sumlen(i)==maximum:
        print i
```

Then you would get the longest pairs (keeps all if not only one):

```
['thisisthelongeststring2', 'thisisthelongeststring3']
['thisisthelongeststring5', 'thisisthelongeststring6']
```

Comment: But, consider you had a very long dictionary, this might take a long time to deliver the results. any ideas how to make it more efficient?

Comment: @sorted You might want to pre-calculate the lengths of each pair and make a list. Then you could find the longest with the list.

Comment: You really want to move `sumlen(max(D.values(), key=sumlen)` calculation *out* of the list comprehension, as this'll be calculated for each list comp iteration otherwise. Not doing so will make your solution take exponential time.

Comment: You can also just pass a generator expression to `sum()`; avoid creating a list object here when all you want to do is sum some lengths.

Comment: Instead of `sumlen(max(D.values(), key=sumlen)`, use `max(sumlen(v) for v in D.values())`; no need to calculate the length sum *twice* for the maximum value.

Comment: With those changes, your solution takes O(2NM) time. N is the size of the dictionary, M the average size of each value list.

Comment: My sorting solution takes O(MNlogN) time; we only need to calculate length sums once (plus a small number of times for the top results + 1).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Did changes. Thank you very much:)

Comment: You can drop the `[..]` brackets and make those generator expressions. Neither `max()` nor `sum()` *have* to have a list, it'll be more efficient if you don't use a list comprehension there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I rarely use generator. Will go to get familiar with it and then come back to modify. Thanks a lot!